# If space projects onto a sphere inside our eye, why do we see flat photographs as normal-looking?

Tags: differential-geometry

In slightly confused. Let's say I take picture with a camera that uses a flat surface to collect an image. When I look at it, I don't see things distorted like it would be with a stereo graphic projection of a sphere onto a flat surface (like a map of the Earth) even though we have a spherical surface collecting light inside our eye.

Can somebody clear this confusion up to me?

Comment: This is more a biology question than a math question. The image processing hardware in your brain has been built specifically to 'transform' the projection onto that curved surface into something perceptable; in particular, to ensure that 'flat' things seem flat.

Comment: Instead of "hardware" it might be more appropriate to use "wetware" :-)